# Windows 7, slow keyboard

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am using Windows 7.  The keyboard requires approximately 1 second of hold down before it sends the letter.  The PC will click once at the 1/2 second then at 1 second the letter will show up.

I thought the keyboard was bad and I purchased a new one (USB) and the same thing happened.  I pulled out an old PS/2 keyboard, and the same thing.

I booted the PC up and went into BIOS.  The keyboard works fine there.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers, no change.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

You may have turned on 'Slow Keys' or 'Filter Keys' by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> for a few seconds.  Doublecheck Control Panel->Ease Of Access (last item)->Ease of Access Center->Change how your keyboard works.  Then unclick 'Turn on Filter Keys'.  You can also look in 'Set up Filter Keys' for related settings.

Answer (score 0):

Change your keyboard properties.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, due to non availability of earthing in the power/current supply, this issue can occur and may be one of the reasons that you are experiencing it.

Please make sure you use three pin plug for the power supply to the CPU.